# Display an Element (select form-group) while loading the page

Tags: jquery, laravel

One of my edit form isn't working as it should.

Please watch the video.

https://watch.screencastify.com/v/vY1UA0Psr095kau0c6BV

You will see that I am circling around a value which is the number of sandwiches (#party_loaf_serving_id) the party loaf should have and then a new element(#party_loaf_weight_id) is displayed once I have changed the value.

I would appreciate some jQuery expertise since I can't find(Css, JQuery or HTML) why the #party_loaf_weight_id isn't displayed when the form is loaded.

I have for example disabled all JQuery parts but the #party_loaf_weight_id isn't loaded and the form-group isn't to find in the HTML|DOM with the browser inspector.

BLADE

```
@if($party_loaf_servings)
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="party_loaf_serving_id" id="party_loaf_serving_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">{{ __('# Sandwichs') }}</option>
            @php
                if (empty($party_loaf_serving_id)) {
                    $party_loaf_serving_id = $orderItem->party_loaf_serving_id;
                }
            @endphp
            @foreach($party_loaf_servings as $serving)
                <option style="color:#6c757d" value="{{ $serving->id }}" {{ ($party_loaf_serving_id == $serving->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $serving->servings }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
@endif

@if($weights)
    <div class="form-group">
        <select name="party_loaf_weight_id" id="party_loaf_weight_id" class="form-control">
            <option value="">{{ __('Poids') }}</option>
            @foreach($weights as $weight)
                <option style="color:#6c757d" value="{{ $weight->id }}" {{ $orderItem->party_loaf_weight_id == $weight->id ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $weight->weight }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
@endif
```

SCRIPTS in blade

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('black/js/blades/order-create-weight.js') }}"></script>

@push('js')
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#party_loaf_serving_id").change(function () {
                const party_loaf_serving_id = $(this).val();
                window.location.href = '{{ route('order.edit-entry-form-block', $orderItem->id) }}/?product_id={{ $orderItem->product_id }}&category_id={{ $orderItem->product_category_id }}&party_loaf_serving_id=' + party_loaf_serving_id;
            });
        }
    </script>
@endpush
```

SCRIPT injection

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    $("#party_loaf_serving").change(function(){

        var servingID = $(this).val();
        alert(servingID);

        if(servingID) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/getWeight/'+servingID,
                type: "GET",
                data : {"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data){
                        $('#party_loaf_weight').empty();
                        $('#party_loaf_weight').append('<option hidden>-- Poids --</option>');
                        $.each(data, function(key, party_loaf_weight){
                            $('select[name="party_loaf_weight"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">' + party_loaf_weight.weight+ '</option>');
                        });
                    }else{
                        $('#party_loaf_weight').empty();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

            else{
                $('#party_loaf_weight').empty();
            }

    });

});
```

ROUTE

```
Route::get('/getWeight/{id}', function ($id) {
$party_loaf_weight = App\PartyLoafWeight::where('serving_id',$id)->get();
return response()->json($party_loaf_weight);
});
```